# Trying to get the previous days date in my batch file name

Tags: batch-file

I have a batch file that saves with the date that it has been run, but i would like it to save it with the previous days date as that is what the data is in the report is for.
I would like the previous days date as it runs automatically the following morning.
Example.Task Scheduler runs task for Mondays report on Tuesday Morning at 5am, and will save incorrectly as"

```
End of Day Monday__2019-10-01_(08-45-00)
```

Where the desired result is:

```
End of Day Monday__2019-09-30_(08-45-00)
```

as it is showing `Tuesdays` date, staff are thinking it is Tuesday data..

I have looked through the website and have tried various codes, but couldn't get them to work.

Below is my code..

```
@echo off
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('wmic OS Get localdatetime ^| find "."') do  set DateTime=%%a

 set Yr=%DateTime:~0,4%
 set Mon=%DateTime:~4,2%
 set Day=%DateTime:~6,2%
 set Hr=%DateTime:~8,2%
 set Min=%DateTime:~10,2%
 set Sec=%DateTime:~12,2%

 set BackupName= End of Day Monday__%Yr%-%Mon%-%Day%_(%H%-%Min%-%Sec%)

 copy "C:\VPRO\DATA\REPORTS\ZHREPRT1.VRP" "C:\End of  Day\%BackupName%.csv"
```

It returns a csv file called  `End of Day Monday__2019-10-01_(08-45-00)`, I want it to return the previous days date..

Comment: [look](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bbatch-file%5D+get+yesterday+date)

Comment: I know you mentioned Task Scheduler, but I just thought I'd ask, which file is being processed on Monday 30th September? Yesterday's, `End of Day Sunday__2019-09-29...`? or possibly the previous work day's, either `End of Day Saturday__2019-09-28...` or `End of Day Friday__2019-09-27...`? What about when running the script after public holidays or shutdowns, or issues with the PC? Yesterday's date wouldn't be relevant in those cases. I'd suggest you retrieve the date directly from `C:\VPRO\DATA\REPORTS\ZHREPRT1.VRP`, then subtract `1` day from that, to build your new filename.

Comment: Hi, It would be the previous days end of day which would be called ZHREPRT1.VRP for Monday and ZHREPRT2.VRP for Tuesday etc                                                                Day 1 = Monday, Day 2 = Tuesday, Day 3 = Wednesday etc..                                                                                     How would i retrieve the date directly from the report, that would be ideal what you are suggesting..

Comment: Well Barry, you'd search for examples of scripts, which retrieve the required date. This is usually it's modification date, but depending upon how your files are used, you may want it's created date, or possibly the earlier of those. Then you'd write your code based upon what you've learned from your search results. If the code you've written doesn't work as written and intended, you would create a new question. That question would show example datestamps and filenames before and after, a [mcve] of the formatted code you used, and what you've tried yourself in fixing the issue before posting.

Answer (score 0):

Use `vbs` with `batch-file` to get a standard date format.

```
@echo off
echo >"%temp%\%~n0.vbs" s=DateAdd("d",-1,now) : d=weekday(s)
echo>>"%temp%\%~n0.vbs" WScript.Echo year(s)^& right(100+month(s),2)^& right(100+day(s),2)
for /f %%a in ('cscript /nologo "%temp%\%~n0.vbs"') do set "mydate=%%a"
set "dd=%mydate:~6,2%"
set "mm=%mydate:~4,2%"
set "yyyy=%mydate:~0,4%"
set "mytime=(%time:~0,2%-%time:~3,2%-%time:~6,2%)"
set "bckname=End of Day Monday__%yyyy%-%mm%-%dd%_%mytime%.csv"
echo %bckname%
del "%temp%\%~n0.vbs" /Q
copy "C:\VPRO\DATA\REPORTS\ZHREPRT1.VRP" "C:\End of  Day\%bckname%"
```

You can change the number of days by changing the second line, currently `-1`

Comment: Thanks for the reply Gerhard. When I set this up i receive 800A0408 error. I have tried changing the type to ANSI, but still no luck.

Comment: `<EndOfYesterday>` isn't neccessarily `Monday`

Comment: @Stephan, yes indeed. I added that because I am not seeing anything in the OP that relates to a translation to day and therefore did not address that issue.

Comment: @BarryHiggins That means there is a character vbs does not like. Did you copy this code as is, or did you make changes to it?

Comment: @Gerhard I copied as is, with no changes. I copied it to Notepad and then saved as .vbs file, which i thought would be okay.

Comment: @Barry: this is a batch file. Save it with extension `.bat`  or `.cmd`.

Comment: @stephan I get the response 'The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.        0 file(s) copied.'                                                                                      I thought it was because it couldn't find the source file, but it is there..

Comment: Please copy the script as is. Save the file as a .cmd or .bat extension file. Ensure you have the right path to the file.

Comment: @Gerhard Perfect all working now, Thank you all very much for your help..